# Why does my WP8 (C#/XAML) app remain "Loading.." forever?

Tags: performance, debugging, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-debugging, windows-phone-8-emulator

What should I look at or step through to try to figure out why my WP8 app displays "Loading..." until the proverbial cows come home (and probably longer, actually). I let it run for a couple of hours that way (while I was doing something else). Just to be sure it wasn't sitting on a breakpoint somewhere without going to it for some reason, I deleted all breakpoints, and it still occurs.

### UPDATE

"Create an application from the default templates and compare the App.xaml.cs constructor to yours."

The only difference between the two App.xaml.cs constructors are:

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true; // new app
Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = false; // existing (not working) app
```

...but it made no difference changing the existing back to what the blank app does as above.

Rather than create a new page, I set the WMAppManifest.xml to use another page (other than MainPage) as the one to navigate to. It still does the "Loading..." business forever, though. It makes it through the NavigatedTo() event, but then just hangs...

The new "main" page's constructor is simply:

```
    InitializeComponent();
```

In the main page, it is:

```
    InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.SizeChanged += ViewStateChanged;
```

### UPDATE 2

A couple of times today I got, "*The network connection to bla.bla.bla.bla has been lost. Debugging will be aborted.*" This wouldn't be a cause of these problems, would it?

The last time it happened (just now) was after shutting down the emulator after it spun through the "Loading..." false promise a few gazillion times (indeterminate progress ring rolling by and by and by...)

### UPDATE 3

Different than Windows Store apps, the page to be navigated to from App.xaml.cs is not specified explicitly. I assume that this, in WMAppManifest.xml:

`<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml"`>

...suffices to navigate/start from MainPage?

Answer (score 3):

Comment the code out of your Application_Launching event handler to make sure that nothing is causing an application hang there.

Create an application from the default templates and compare the App.xaml.cs constructor to yours.  Make sure the initialization steps aren't missed.  That's where the code that sets up the root frame and navigates to the start page is found.  Finally, create a new blank page and set it as the start page in your WMAppManifest.xml.  If that navigation works, then the issue is in the constructor or OnNavigatedTo method of your main page.

Comment: My answer to your good suggestions are lengthy, so I'm adding them above as an Update.

Comment: You could check the application resources created in App.xaml or in any merged dictionaries to see if their initialization code hangs you're app.  These styles are loaded as part of the initialization process.  Do you have a sample project you can share?  The answer is probably something simple.  I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: I don't make use of merged dictionaries or non-standard resources.

I could email you the project if you want to take a look; I failed to note earlier: there's also an associated ancillary project(ScheduledTaskAgent), and geolocation code that runs in the background when the user's location changes.